# Users to create a quiz for other users to take?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm fairly new to SpringBoot and was hoping that someone here could push me in the right direction. How do I build the functionality for a quiz to be created by a user within my app, and for other users to take the quiz?

I currently have a spring boot backend that does jwt authentication and authorization. The front end is in Vue.JS. The next step is to build the quiz capabilities.

The admin should be able to:

- write a question
- populate 4 multiple choice answer options for that question
- indicate which option is correct
- Add more questions dynamically

The user should be able to:

- attempt the quiz
- get scored on their answers to the quiz
- only have one attempt per quiz

Comment: What tasks do you need to complete? Write questions, edit questions, format questions, choose type of questions? multiple choice, short answer, drag & drop,  select from list? Structure quiz - how many questions, marking, tolerance on numerical answers? So much that you need to consider.

Comment: check for some examples on google. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqLl7mckWv8    https://github.com/oojorgeoo89/QuizZz